# Does the destructor get called automatically

Tags: c++, destructor

My question is simple, but I haven't been able to find the question anywhere.

If I have a class like such

```
class A {
    vector<int> data;
}
```

When an instance of `A` gets destroyed will `data` also get destroyed properly, or should I write a destructor for `A` that calls `data`'s destructor? Basically I worried about whether the dynamic memory of vector will not be freed when an instance of `A` is destroyed. I suspect the answer is that `data` is freed properly, but I don't want to find out I'm wrong the hard way.

Further, if `A` was a struct would the destructor for `data` get called when a local instance of `A` falls out of scope?

Comment: You are lacking a semi-colon after the declaration of `class A` (which is not really a declaration since it's lacking... oh well).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, `data` will be destroyed automatically, you need not do anything to achieve it. `vector` will handle the cleaning up of the dynamic memory allocated by it. The vector's destructor will be called automatically when an instance of `A` is destroyed.

There is no difference in behavior irrespective of whether `A` is a `class` or `struct`.

Comment: +1 Just to be clear, "vector will handle the cleaning up of the dynamic memory allocated *by* it", not *to* it. If you store dynamically allocated objects in a vector, it's your responsibility to `delete` them accordingly.

Comment: @netcoder find your comment a bit misleading. You can store in a vector **pointers to dynamically allocated objects** but I don't think that you can store the "objects" themselves that are dynamically allocated in a vector. If you declare a vector<ClassA> where ClassA is a class name, then vector will take care of the destruction of the ClassA objects that it holds. Of course, if your ClassA objects hold pointers to other objects, then it is **ClassA's responsibility to delete them**, **NOT the responsibility of vector**, but that's another story.

Answer (score 4):

No need, data member's destructors are always called.

An explicit destructor is useful manual memory management

```
struct a{
    int* ip;
    a() 
    : ip(new int(5)) 
    { }

    ~a() { delete ip; }
};
```

That said, you should generally speaking use RAII containers (such as smart pointers) so I personally rarely write dtors there days.

And exception to that is to declare a base classes dtor as virtual.

```
struct base {
     virtual ~base() {}
};
struct child : public base {
    //base and child destructor automatically called 
}
```

Comment: +1 for adhering to good RAII principles. The need to manually write destructors should be getting less and less when people are coding C++ the way Stroustrup, Sutter, Meyers, and other modern C++ thinkers intend us to write it.

Answer (score 1):

A default-destructor is created automatically by the compiler if you do not define one yourself.  In general, you do not need to create your own destructor unless you have pointer data-members that "own" the memory they point to, and/or you are designing your class to be derived by other classes, at which point you would want to at least declare an empty `virtual` destructor.

In all cases, both with your own destructor, as well as the default compiler-created destructor, all destructors for non-static data-members as well as any base-classes of the current class are called at the end of the destructor and before the destructor function itself returns.